# I am building a circuit that operates at 5 V but I need to use SIM7600 module @12 V

Tags: arduino, 12v, 5v

I am building a circuit with an Arduino that operates at 5 V, but I need to use a [SIM7600 module](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SIM7600CE-T_4G(LTE)_Shield_V1.0_SKU_TEL0124) that will be connected to the Arduino's pins, and needs 12 V in order to operate.

Will I have any problems if everything (Arduino, sensors, power supply, etc.) needs 5 V, but I include the SIM7600 module that demands 12 V (with a 5 V to 12 V step-up) on the same circuit?

Comment: Please show/link the document that suggests 12 volts is needed by the SIM7600

Comment: None of the SIM7600 bare modules appear to be powered by 12V.  In fact, they all appear to operate at 3.3V.  Please give us a link to the actual module you're using.

Comment: https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SIM7600CE-T_4G(LTE)_Shield_V1.0_SKU_TEL0124   ---> Input Power: VIN(7-23V)/USB(5V)

Comment: That module looks like it should work if plugged into an Arduino board since it looks like the two main power rails (3.3V and 5V) can be powered from onboard converters or directly from the carrier board.

Comment: how do you deduce `module that demands 12 V ` when the  specification is  `VIN(7-23V)`?

Comment: It is the mainstream to use fix voltage equals to 12 Volts for that kind of modules... And it is inside the range 7-23 Volts.... Also If you use 7 or 8 Volts the Amperes that the module demands will lower the voltage so you cannot use 7 Volts...As far as I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIM7600CE-T basic spec you link to is very summary, curt in places.

But, as shown below, it states that a 5 V supply can be taken from its USB connector.

That means you don't need a step-up regulator.

[image]

Comment: So I can attach the SIM7600CE-T to the Arduino, supply the Arduino via its USB and supply the SIM7600CE-T via its USB and everything fine? Am I missing something at this point??

Comment: @just_learning, according to that datasheet, yes you can. We're all missing the detail that the documentation lacks.